# datagridview AutoResizeRow function but for a single row

Tags: c#-4.0, datagridview

In my current grid, I have the datagridview AutoResizeRow = true and it looks fine.  The grid only has two columns: the first one being a CheckBoxColumn and the second a TextBoxColumn. The rows that have a long string text in the textbox automatically grow to display multiple lines and the ones with short strings look fine (showing the size of a single height row).

What I need is the ability to only allow the cells to expand (when they have long strings of data) when the user clicks on the cell, then collapse down to a single row height size when the user clicks to another cell or moves off the control.  So, only expand to show multiple lines when the user clicks into the cell.

Can this be done? If so, can you provide sample code in C#?

Comment: There is no offending code. I searched countless websites looking for code that would selectively turn-on/off the AutoResizeRow functionally, but "per row" not "per grid".  Or is there a way for me to know the optimum size of a row, based on the size of the contents (like what AutoResizeRow does so i can set the height when the user clicks in or out of a cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check on this event

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Visible = false;
}
```